# Rails error Couldn't find Album without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display all Reviews a User wrote on the users show page. Users have many albums and reviews. Reviews belong to albums and users. Albums have many reviews and users. I want to link the Review.title to the albums show page belonging to that review. I'm pretty new to Rails so I'm not sure what code to add to make this work.

Error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find Album without an ID
Extracted source (around line #60):
58
59
60
61
62
63


    def find_album
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
    end

    def user_params
```

users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_current_user, only: [:index, :show, :new, :edit, :destroy]
    #before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :find_album, only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :must_login, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @users = User.all
    end

    def show
        @reviews = @user.reviews

    end

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            session[:user_id] = @user.id
            redirect_to albums_path
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        @user.update(user_params(:name, :email, :password_digest))
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
    end

    def destroy
        @user = User.destroy
    end

    private

   # def set_review
   #     @review = Review.find(params[:id])
   # end

    def set_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_current_user
        @user = current_user
    end

    def find_album
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
    end

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    validates :email, uniqueness: true, presence: true, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }
    validates :name, uniqueness: true, length: {in: 3..20}, presence: true
    has_many :reviews
    has_many :albums, through: :reviews

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize do |user|
          user.provider = auth.provider
          user.uid = auth.uid
          user.name = auth.info.name
          user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
          user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
          user.save!
        end
      end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#omniauth'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get '/signup' => 'users#new', as: 'signup'
  post '/signup' => 'users#create'
  get '/signin' => 'sessions#new'
  post '/signin' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/signout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  post '/logout', to: "sessions#destroy"

  resources :albums do
    resources :reviews, except: [:index]
  end
  resources :users, only: [:show, :destroy]
  resources :reviews, only: [:index]

  root to: "albums#index"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

users#show.html.erb

```
<p>Here is a list of Reviews you wrote:</p>
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
        <%= link_to review.title, album_path(@album) %><br>
        <%= review.content %><br>
        <br>
<% end %>

<br>
<% if @user.reviews == nil? %>
<p>No reviews yet!</p>
<p>Choose from the list of albums to review <%= link_to "here!", albums_path %></p>
<% end %>
```

Albums controller

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_album, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :must_login, only: [:new, :show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @albums = Album.all
        @user = current_user
    end

    def show
        @review = @album.reviews.build
        @review.user = current_user

        @review.save
        @reviews = Review.recent #scope
    end

    def new
        @album = Album.new
        @review = @album.reviews.build
        @user = current_user
    end

    def create
        #@user = User.find(current_user.id)
        @album = current_user.albums.build(album_params)
        #@album.user_id = current_user.id
        @album.reviews.each { |r| r.user ||= current_user } # I'm using ||= so i can use the same code on update without changing reviews that already have a user
        if @album.save
            redirect_to album_path(@album)
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
        @user = current_user
    end

    def update
        #@album = current_user.albums.build(album_params)
        @album.user_id = current_user.id
        if @album.update(album_params)
            redirect_to album_path(@album), notice: "Your album has been updated."
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @album.delete
        @album.avatar.purge
        redirect_to albums_path
    end

    private

    def set_album
        @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    end

    def album_params
        params.require(:album).permit(:artist, :title, :avatar, :user_id, reviews_attributes:[:title, :date, :content]) #removed the :user_id and :album_id from the permitted parameters for reviews_attributes, don't want users to exploit that assignation adding those parameters that I'm actually not using
    end
end
```

Reviews controller

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :set_current_user, only: [:index, :show, :new, :edit, :destroy]
    before_action :find_album, only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :must_login, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @albums = Album.with_recent_reviews
    end

    def show

        #@reviews = Review.where("album_id = ?", params[:album_id])
    end

    def new
        if params[:album_id] && @album = Album.find_by(id: params[:client_id])
            @review = @album.reviews.build
        else
            redirect_to albums_path
        end
    end

    def create
        @review = current_user.reviews.build(review_params)
        @review.album = @album
        if @review.save
            redirect_to album_path(@album)
        else
            @album = @review.album
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @review.update(review_params)
            redirect_to album_path(params[:album_id])
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        if current_user.id == @review.user_id
          @album.reviews.find(params[:id]).destroy
          redirect_to album_path(params[:album_id])
        else
           flash[:error] = "Unable to delete your review. Please try again."
           redirect_to album_reviews_path(@review)
        end
      end

    private

    def set_review
        @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_current_user
        @user = current_user
    end

    def find_album
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
    end

    def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:title, :date, :content, album_attributes:[:artist, :title, :user_id])
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a routes problem. The magic is done with **nested routes** and single controllers: There should be a users_controller and and albums_controller and a reviews_controller. The you can just use something like user.albums and user.reviews once you found the user via id.

From: https://medium.com/podiihq/understanding-rails-routes-and-restful-design-a192d64cbbb5

> Rails allows you to organize groups of controllers under a namespace with a keyword “namespace” during routing.
>
> For instance grouping Articles and Comments Controllers under Admin controller.
>
> ```
> namespace :admin do 
>  resources :articles, :comments
> end
> ```
>
> To get to the articles on your browser you have to prefix it with admin , that is /admin/articles

In the end, once you created/updated your routes to something like

I think you can either use namespace or resources like

```
resources :users do 
 resources :reviews, :albums
end
```

and controllers you can use the following code in your users controller:

```
  def index
    @reviews= @user.reviews
    @albums = @user.albums
  end
```

See also here, a sample with sharks: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-nested-resources-for-a-ruby-on-rails-application

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, i actually have an albums controller and a reviews controller. I'll post those too

Answer (score 0):

Since users `have_many :reviews` and reviews `belong_to :user`, all you have to do is this:

```
def show
  @reviews = @user.reveiws
end
```

Then in your `show.html.erb` file, you can iterate over the `@reviews` and pull out whatever you want from the review.

```
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
  <p><%= link_to review.title, album_path(review.album) %></p>
  <p><%= review.content %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: hmmm this gave me the following error for the link_to line pointing to users#show: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"albums", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Were you able to look at it?